# How to send emoji in Telegram bot with python?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm dealing with a small project, I decided to add emoji to make the visual a little better, but I couldn't send it. I tried Unicodes like "\U000203C" or even tried to copy the emoji and past it but still can't do it. Is there any way that I can send emoji?

**Unicode**

```
exchange_msg = "TRY TO USD: "+ USDTORTY, "PERCANTAGE: " +  USDTORTYPERCENTAGE + u'\U000203C'
update.message.reply_text(exchange_msg)
```

**Copy-Paste**

```
exchange_msg = "TRY TO USD: "+ USDTORTY, "PERCANTAGE: " +  USDTORTYPERCENTAGE + u''
update.message.reply_text(exchange_msg)
```

The outputs of the codes I tried are as follows below.

```
["TRY TO USD: 7.8645", "PERCANTAGE: -0.0151 (-0.19%)\ud83d\udea8"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply message is a tuple

```
exchange_msg = "TRY TO USD: "+ USDTORTY, "PERCANTAGE: " +  USDTORTYPERCENTAGE + u''

# print type: <class 'tuple'>
print(type(exchange_msg))
# print second value: PERCANTAGE: USDTORTYPERCENTAGE 
print(exchange_msg[1])
# print second value type: <class 'str'>
print(type(exchange_msg[1]))
```

You can easily use emoij in text messages as long a they are part of a String.
You could change your code to use a single string as response (which is a good way to map a reply) or alternatively access directly the tuple values

```
# replacing comma with a space
exchange_msg = "TRY TO USD: " + 'USDTORTY' + " " + "PERCANTAGE: " + 'USDTORTYPERCENTAGE ' + ''
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a running bot and I use a lot of emojis. I use https://www.iemoji.com/ to find the Python Src to the emoji I want to use, then I code.

This is my way to do it:

```
def emojis (update, context):
    msg = '\U0001F916 This is a Robot face!\n'
    msg += '\uE404 This is a smiling face!'
    context.bot.send_message(message_id = update.message.message_id,
                             chat_id = update.message.chat_id,
                             text = msg)
```

Comment: To add to it, one need to click on the detail page of a emoji and scroll down: https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/506/symbols/double-exclamation-mark :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to show your emojis in python.

1. By emoji **name** (You can find your names in this [unicode.org](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html))

   ```py
   print('\N{Sauropod}')
   ```
2. By emoji **unicode** (It should be 8 characters, hence, put some zeros after \U)

   ```py
   print('\U0001F534')
   ```