# How to send text msg with emoji in Telegram with python?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

hello friends I want to send a Text message with emojis but I can't able to send when I add emoji to a text msg it stops working

I want to send a message like this -

**Hello friends  how are you**

and this is the code I use. if anyone knows how to send emojis and text at the same time plz help

```
   print("Sending Message to:", user['name'])
   client.send_message(receiver, message)
   print("Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME))
   time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send emoji in Telegram bot with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452196/how-to-send-emoji-in-telegram-bot-with-python)